# tcp socket data out of order?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp

When sending data over a socket, I read that the individual messages can be fragemented, so that I receive differently sized packages then I sent. That's ok and easy to deal with.

However, I'm a bit unsure if these messages could also arrive out of order? Is a TCP socket like a stream, so that the order is garuanteed? I tried to find some information on this via google, but so far I haven't found anything.
If packages can arrive out of order I also wonder how to deal with it, if I can not rely on a particular size or order?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol - "TCP provides reliable, **ordered**, [...]"

Comment: Yes, TCP reorders packets that arrive out-of-order, providing a stream interface.

Comment: To be clear, TCP handles that for you. If you use UDP you might get messages out of order, missing messages etc.

Comment: Yes I was aware of the UDP sockets, but unsure about TCP as I never did any networking related before.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this question is based on a misconception. There is no such thing as "messages" when it comes to TCP. TCP is *not* a message protocol. So it would be impossible for TCP to return messages out of order even if it wanted to -- it would have no way to know where the messages began and ended!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your application will get **ordered** data stream.

Let kernel do the stuff about packet loss, ordering, etc. - its out of your bussiness.